# function name($param, $line = __LINE__, $file = __FILE__) {};

Tags: php, function, defaults

Is it possible to have a function automatically contain the line number and the file that the function was CALLED in,

as if i call `__LINE__` or `__FILE__` in the function it will use the line and file the function definition is in.

but i dont want to have to pass `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` into the function every time.

so if i set them as the default params, do they come from the function definition, or where it is being called from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way would be using [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace), but as the name says: it is for debugging. Your code should **not** attach any meaning or functionality in production based on where/when it's called.

Comment: may i ask why this is so bad?

Comment: (1) debug_backtrace has quite a lot of overhead (2) your functions behavior gets unpredictable for other developers (a decorator or just perhaps proper private/protected/public methods, depending on circumstances, would be far more recognizable solutions) (3) the function breaks out of its self containment / independence, which is about the surest sign there is something wrong with the design.

Comment: @Hailwood in production environment all inner nitty-gritty details should be logged, not displayed to user. that's what Wrikken about. And for debugging purposes there is a function called `trigger_error` which will luckily add file and line automatically, outputting error message according to current error handling settings - to display or a log file. very handy

Answer (score 6):

Doing what you suggest doesn't seem to work.

You can do it like this, but I'm not sure why you want to do it and that there isn't a better approach to what you are trying to achieve - see [Wrikken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387320/function-nameparam-line-line-file-file/3387354#3387354).

```
<?php

function test() {
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $last = $backtrace[0];
    echo "{$last['function']}() called from {$last['file']} line {$last['line']}\r\n"; 
}



test();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so late but maybe can be useful, you can use get_called_class(), for the name of class who is called, and do not pass like a parameter insted of **CLASS**.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use this information in some kind of error message, there is a function `trigger_error()` which will raise PHP native error, so, therefore, it will be shown in usual PHP manner - with filename, line number and supplied text.

Most neat feature of this function is behaving according to current error handling settings:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
trigger_error("Horrible bug found!");
```

will print out directly to screen an error message like this:

```
Notice: Horrible bug found! in /path/file.php on line 2
```

very handy for developing
while this code

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
trigger_error("Horrible bug found!");
```

will be put into error log for the future reference
obligatory for the production