# determine from where the function being called in php

Tags: php, error-handling

I have one function on my code. say its xyz().

This function is being called from different files of my project.

Is there any way than I can get from where the function is being called.

I want below infromation:

> File name from where its called. Line
>   number of that file. if call is from
>   inside the function then that function
>   name. Class name Class method name.

I know about use of magic constants like **FILE** and all that. but i don't want to pass all that in function call. like below:

```
xyz('msg',__FILE__,__CLASS__);
```

is there any way that i have to pass just my error related data only. and it will find the above details from where the function is called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387320/function-nameparam-line-line-file-file.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [debug_backtrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function:

```
function myFunctionToDebug()
{
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}
```

This function returns an array with all information you need for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) or debug_backtrace() by any chance?

Comment: its giving the whole trace, but i want to determine only from the function was called... does that make sense...?